# One computer is not able to receive ARP replies (ping) in a local network

Tags: networking, ping, tcpdump, arp

I have two computers connected via a router (modem), and I can't ping one from the other. I'm running `ARP`, `TCP` dump on both of them. The `ARP` requests from System 1 are getting passed on to system 2, System 2 replies to them, but System 1 cant receive those replies. System 1 on the other hand cant receive any `ARP` requests from System 2.

Any solutions?

Comment: It is not very clear. What do you mean with "two computers connected via a router"? ARP packets can't be routed. Can you edit your question adding  `ipconfig` and `route` output for both systems?

Comment: My modem has 4 lan ports, and both the computers are connected to it..

Comment: @user2277550 Did you able to resolve. i am facing similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities I see:

- Router (switch?) is misbehaving... can you try another one?
- IP is duplicated, or Mask is incorrect... Check that the mask is the same and the IP different, but in same network.
- Ultra rare case where there is a duplicate MAC... Check MAC on the two sysems.
- ARP Cache problem... check your cache, like `cat /proc/net/arp`
- ARP is malformed... check that the Address Resolution Protocol SHA SPA THA TPA are proper in your dump.

(perhaps post the ARP dump)